# Swift Firestore prevent checking if Dictionary key exists

Tags: swift, google-cloud-firestore

I have this chunk of code which returns the results from a Firestore query. Because I want to make sure that the values exists I'm checking every single one of them like `if let driverLat = packageDetails["driverLat"] as? Double.. etc` and also casting them. It is getting really annoying and I was wondering if there is a better solution to this?

```
db.collection("packages").document(documentID).getDocument() { (document, error) in
    if let document = document, document.exists {
        if let packageDetails = document.data() as [String: AnyObject]? {
            if let driverLat = packageDetails["driverLat"] as? Double, let driverLon = packageDetails["driverLon"] as? Double {
                if let destinationLat = packageDetails["destinationLat"] as? Double, let destinationLon = packageDetails["destinationLon"] as? Double {
                    // more code
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would say that you should use multiple `guard-let` statements. This prevents the pyramid shaped code which decreases the readability.

It would look like so:

```
typealias Json = [String: AnyObject]

db.collection("packages").document(documentID).getDocument() { (document, error) in
    guard let document       = document, document.exists else { return }
    guard let packageDetails = document.data() as Json? else { return }

    guard let driverLat      = packageDetails["driverLat"] as? Double else { return }
    guard let driverLon      = packageDetails["driverLon"] as? Double else { return }

    guard let destinationLat = packageDetails["destinationLat"] as? Double else { return }
    guard let destinationLon = packageDetails["destinationLon"] as? Double else { return }

    // more code
}
```